# In an object, should I put an id to another object, or the full object?

Tags: java, android, sql, oop

I have 2 objects : Product and Form.

Product :

```
private int id;
private int metricId;
private int projectId;
private String brand;
private String name;
```

Form :

```
private int id;
private int captureId;
private Product product;
private String qty;
private String picture;
private String validation;
```

So inside Form, I have a Product Object.

Thing is when I have to deal with SQL, I always need to manipulate product_id.

So my question is : in Form Definition, Should I have the whole Product "product" field or just the id : productId?

When I make a query, I get a difficulty :

```
// Getting single Form
public Form getForm(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DatabaseManager.getInstance().openDatabase();
    Form form = null;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FORM + " WHERE " + FORM_ID
            + " = " + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        form = new Form();
        form.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        form.setCaptureId(cursor.getInt(1));
        form.setProductId(cursor.getInt(2)); // <-- I have no ProductId, just an Object
        form.setQty(cursor.getString(6));
        form.setPic(cursor.getString(7));
        form.setSync(cursor.getInt(8));
    }
```

In this type of query, I feel that my object should have only the id, because otherwise, I should have a join of each Form Query to get the product inside .

I feel the first is more "Java" and the second more "Sql". So I can't decide myself !
Any Opinion is welcome !

Comment: Most of the time when you use an ORM, you don't construct the objects yourself, you let the system do it for you:  you end up calling something like `Form obj = dbManager.findById(id, Form.class);`  No need to write SQL, it grabs dependent objects for you (at some point), etc.  You're required to do mapping at some point (whether by object member names matching, annotations, or xml files), but simplifies the base-idiot-monkey job.  Otherwise, you have to do a `JOIN` in your query, or a separate query to get the `Product` object data (but db round-trips are usually expensive).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use only the ID. This is a form of normalization if I am not wrong. The join should help you while retrieval as you have mentioned.

Comment: Presumably he _has_ a normalized table structure, the problem is dealing with the ORM mapping.  At which point he's dealing with the complete objects, not raw db rows (well, sort of...).

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of keeping the form has a product relationship is that you are able to encapsulate the different ideas of a product and form.  While in your scenario just having the id is acceptable the challenge comes as the application grows and you need to represent the relationship between form and product. For example what happens when you need to persist a form and its product information?  Then you will need the product to still be part of the form.

Generally speaking its best to develop a clear domain model in the java code because its more flexible than just attaching ID's to different objects.